# python; how to pass one argument through multiple methods in a class

Tags: python

I am learning about class structure in python. Would like to know if it's possible to pass one argument through more than one method.

```
class Example(object):

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def square(self):
        return self.x**2

    def cube(self):
        return self.x**3

    def squarethencube(y):
        sq = Example.square(y)
        cu = Example.cube(sq)
        return cu


two = Example(2)

print(two.squarethencube())
```

Error is on line 10; AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'x'

The goal is to use the 'squarethencube' method to pass '2' to square(), which is 4. Then pass '4' to cube(). The desired output is '64'. Obviously, you can write a function to do the math in a very simple way; the question here is how to use multiple methods.

I understand the error in that .x is getting assigned as an attribute onto the output of cube(sq). I was getting the same error, but on line 7, before I changed the argument to y (from self.x).

I've found some similar answers here but I need a simpler explanation.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Please describe more clearly what your expected output is, as well as what state you expect the value `x` to be in after the operation.

Comment: You forgot `self` in `def squarethencube`. Also `return self.x**6`.

Comment: Do you want to use the two saved in self.x or pass in a new argument when you call squarethencube()?

Comment: You should use `def squarethencube(self):` then use `return Example(self.square()).cube()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this seems like the simplest fix. Thank you. I just needed to know the correct way to call it.

Comment: @Christy of defined that way, the `two.squarethencube()` should work.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes!

Answer (score 4):

Currently, `square` and `cube` are methods bound to the class; however, you are accessing them in `squarethencube` by class name, but they are methods, and thus rely on a reference to the class from an instance. Therefore, you can either create two new instances of the class or use `classmethod`:

Option1:

```
class Example(object):

   def __init__(self, x):
      self.x = x

   def square(self):
      return self.x**2

   def cube(self):
      return self.x**3

   def squarethencube(self, y):
      sq = Example(y).square()
      cu = Example(y).cube()
      return cu
```

Option 2: use a classmethod:

```
class Example(object):

   def __init__(self, x):
      self.x = x
   @classmethod
   def square(cls, x):
      return x**2
   @classmethod
   def cube(cls, x):
      return x**3

   def squarethencube(self, y):
      sq = Example.square(y)
      cu = Example.cube(sq)
      return cu
```

Comment: What is the distinction here between `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod`?  Is `@classmethod` preferred?

Comment: @alex I prefer `@staticmethod` for functions that don't depend on the class. In that case it's a namespacing preference.

Comment: @alex: It depends on the implementation. `@classmethod` requires at least one parameter to contain the classname attribute which is automatically passed to the function, which can then be used to access class variables. `@staticmethod` does not require the first classname parameter, however, in order to access class variables or functions bound to the class via `classmethod` or `staticmethod`, you will have to manually specify the class or use `self.__class__`.

Comment: Your classmethod example doesn't work because y, as the first argument in squarethencube() is being considered ```self``` and the x***2 in square() is trying to square a class. You should either change both instances of y to ```self.x``` to use the value stored on __init__ or, add change the definition to ```def squarethencube(self, y)``` to allow y to be passed in as an argument

Comment: @divibisan opps, forgot the `self`. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Also, in the first case, square and cube don't take arguments and sq needs to be passed into the second definition of Example: ```cu = Example(sq).cube()```

Comment: @alex I almost never use @staticmethod and ismply make module-level functions. `classmethod` is sometimes useful, e.g. alternative constructors.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Example:
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x

  def square(self):
    return self.x**2

  def cube(self):
    return self.x**3

  def squarethencube(self):
    return (self.x**2)**3
two = Example(2)

print(two.squarethencube())
```